Laravel 10, se ejecuta un fichero de migraciones eliminado
He eliminado el fichero de migraciones que trae Laravel 10.10 "2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table.php".
Pero aparece en la terminal que se ejecuta con las demás migraciones y me crea la correspondiente tabla.
El fichero no esta entre los ficheros de la aplicación ni en vendor, tampoco tengo por ningún lado un Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', ...);.
Elimine las tablas varias veces, manualmente y con php artisan db:wipe, elimine la BD y la volví a crear. Borre cache...
¿Alguna idea?
