Ejecución de Migration Inexistente Laravel
Cordial saludo,
Estoy modificando las migraciones de mi aplicación en Laravel 10. Sin embargo, aunque haya eliminado todas las migraciones de la carpeta database/migrations, sigue ejecutándose la migración 2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table. Mi duda es: ¿por qué sigue ejecutándose esa migración aunque el archivo ya no exista?
Lo pregunto porque en mi aplicación debo ejecutar primero otras migraciones antes que esta. Si coloco la migración nuevamente, me da el error de que la tabla ya existe.

Por ejemplo, esto sucede cuando creo una migración de nombre similar pero con diferente fecha


No te parece más extraño que teniendo vacío ese directorio se ejecuten migraciones en general? Donde están las migraciones de 2024? Por qué se ejecutan también esas si está vacío el directorio?

Te remito a mi publicación de hace unos meses, mismo tema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/623639/laravel-10-se-ejecuta-un-fichero-de-migraciones-eliminado

Después de un borrado manual de migraciones, hay que hacer lo siguiente para limpiar la cache
php artisan cache:clear

Y luego:
php artisan migrate

Si esto no funciona, podríamos revisar lo siguiente...
Al instalar ciertos paquetes de Laravel, algunos de ellos pueden contener migraciones en ellas, estas deberían ubicarse en:
/src/vendor/laravel/{PACKAGE_NAME}/database/migrations/{MIGRATION_FILENAME.php}

Al momento de realizar las migraciones, estos archivos son copiados al directorio y se vuelve a realizar la migracion.
Si has instalado paquetes, te recomiendo revisar estas carpetas y comprobar si tienen migraciones existentes.
